# Getting "Single stepping until exit from function CALayerGetDelegate, which has no line number information." in iphone sdk

Tags: calayer, ios4

My code is as follows:

```
if ([dematAllocationDict count] > 0)
    {
        [dematTableV reloadData]; // debugger stops here
        dematTableV.hidden = FALSE;
    }
```

When I call the method  , my code runs good at first time. But when I call it again then I am getting the message in console, i.e.

"Single stepping until exit from function CALayerGetDelegate,  which has no line number information."

I tried a lot but not getting the solution. When I do continue to run the app then it gives `BAD ACCESS.`

Debugger stops at :

```
 [dematTableV reloadData];
```

Please help me... :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit it into some more readable format